# How to allow only a specific number of data entries in a column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a shared file, in which I want to have an upper limit of data entries in the columns. For example, I want to have a maximum of 5 entries, and when a user tries to insert a 6th one, they should receive a warning message and their input should be rejected.

I have tried with data validation and COUNTA, but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: I just want to not allow people to insert more than 5 entries in a column. There is no point in sharing an example.

Comment: Probably the simplest way would be to lock the sheet and unlock certain cells.

Answer (score 1):

use this on a range of the whole column:

```
=COUNTA(A$1:A)<6
```

[image]